# For every 3 rows, take a random row from the 3 out into a test data frame. (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe(df) set up in a way that each 3 rows is a biological triplicate.

Firstly, for every 3 rows, I'd like to randomly select 1 row out of the 3, take it out of df and put it in df_test.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
df_test <- df %>%
  group_by(grp = (row_number()-1) %/% 3) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `sample` all at once. If each group is a block of `n` rows, sample randomly an offset of `0:(n-1)` from the start of each block, and add it to the start of each block - `seq(1, nrow(df), n)`.

```
n <- 3
s <- seq(1, nrow(df), n)
df[sample(0:(n-1), length(s)) + s,]
```

Try it with 1000 runs and the distribution of rows selected seems pretty uniform:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:18, ncol=2))
n <- 3
s <- seq(1, nrow(df), n)
table(replicate(1000, sample(0:(n-1), length(s)) + s))

#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
#341 329 330 325 344 331 334 327 339
```